# Hosting a python discord bot on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py, hosting

Hello I just hosted my bot on heroku It's working normally on vscode but when I start it on heroku I am getting this issue :

```
2021-10-06T13:46:25.731963+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python crypto_bot.py`

2021-10-06T13:46:26.739615+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-10-06T13:46:27.351804+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-10-06T13:46:27.351822+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/crypto_bot.py", line 4, in <module>

2021-10-06T13:46:27.351913+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
from crypto_functions import get_crypto_price,get_crypto_rank,get_price_with_symbol,get_performance_24,get_performance_7d,get_everything_about_the_crypto,get_crypto_info,get_crypto_reddit,get_crypto_price_in_numbers_only

2021-10-06T13:46:27.351914+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/crypto_functions.py", line 19, in <module>
2021-10-06T13:46:27.351996+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
 json_file=json.loads(response.text)['data']

2021-10-06T13:46:27.351996+00:00 app[worker.1]: KeyError: 'data'

2021-10-06T13:46:27.523411+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with 
status 1

2021-10-06T13:46:27.574770+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the dictionary that you get from response.text doesn't have a `data` key. Probably the file you get that from doesn't exist or have a different value. If that's a file generated by the program it could be a persistence problem since heroku doesn't have it.

Comment: the file is generated by the api when I make a request does that mean that heroku does not support that?

Comment: No, heroku have no persistence, I'd recommend something like replit for this kind of stuff.